# How to view the source code implemetation of a function/method in Maple?

Tags: algorithm, symbolic-math, maple

I tried the following:

```
interface(verboseproc=2);
readlib(FormalPowerSeries);
```

but I don't get the source code, instead I get the following lines:

```
module()
local UpdateCoeff,ComplexApart,RationalAlgorithm,constantRE,PSInt,PS,hypergeomRE,de2re,hypergeomRsolve,printDE,DIRECTION,simpl,FindDE,Limit,Recursion,RecursionSimplify,Pochhammer,simpreal,simppoch,simpfact,tofact,`FPS/Hankel1`,`FPS/Hankel2`,`FPS/JacobiP`,`FPS/Bateman`,`FPS/ExpIntegralE`,`FPS/Abramowitz`,`FPS/Fibonacci`,`FPS/LegendreP`,`FPS/LegendreQ`,`FPS/ChebyshevT`,`FPS/ChebyshevU`,`FPS/LaguerreL`,standardsum,REorder,subsspecfunc,SUBS,mysolve;
export FPS,HolonomicDE,SimpleRE,_pexports,`convert/RESol`;
global `diff/FPS/Hankel1`,`diff/FPS/Hankel2`,`diff/FPS/JacobiP`,`diff/FPS/LegendreP`,`diff/FPS/LegendreQ`,`diff/FPS/ChebyshevT`,`diff/FPS/ChebyshevU`,`diff/FPS/LaguerreL`,`diff/FPS/Bateman`,`diff/FPS/ExpIntegralE`,`diff/FPS/Abramowitz`,`diff/FPS/Fibonacci`,`convert/FormalPowerSeries`,`convert/FPS`;

end module
```

Is there any way to view the source code implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
restart:

interface(verboseproc=3): # verbose printing of procedure bodies

exports(FormalPowerSeries); # those which you can normally print

eval(FormalPowerSeries:-FPS); # printing one of the exports

eval(FormalPowerSeries); # the shell of the module, showing locals

# normally, you cannot print the locals
eval(FormalPowerSeries:-RationalAlgorithm);

kernelopts(opaquemodules=false): # allowing printing of the locals

eval(FormalPowerSeries:-RationalAlgorithm);
```

Comment: is there any similar way we can view source in mathematica 8 too ?

Comment: @saint1729 Use function ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions``,such as ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Plot]``

Comment: What does it mean if the output is simply `module() ... end module`?  Does it mean that the source code for this function is not readable or that it needs to be read in a different way? I am new to Maple and I am a bit confused about why a callable object is a `module` and not `proc`.

Comment: If a module has a local called `ModuleApply` then the name (to which the whole module is assigned) can be called as if it were a procedure. This is sometimes called an "appliable module". For example `f:=module()...end module` that contains a `local` named `ModuleApply` to which is defined as a procedure. In this case you can call `f(2.1)` as if `f` were itself a procedure. One gets the benefits of callable procedures but also with the ability to carry ancilliary data/procedures within themselves. Hard to explain perfectly in a Comment.

Comment: As an example, in recent Maple versions such as Maple 2019.0 the command `sqrt` is implemented as an appliable module. See the output from issuing `op(2,eval(sqrt));` say. And then you can issue `showstat(sqrt::ModuleApply);` to see the main entry-point that one gets when issuing, say, `sqrt(256);` etc.

Comment: A module is a container with exports and locals (the latter not accessible from outside, by default). The locals can be procedures or other structures. As mentioned, if the module assigned to `f` has the specially named local `ModuleApply` then `f` can be called on arguments. A contrast with a procedure assigned to `F` is that each call to `F` has to recreate/reassign its local helper procs, whereas the appliable module assigned to `f` has its module-local helper procs defined just once when the module is defined.